# Перелистывание на ios

Tags: ipad, ios

Собственно вопрос: пишу программу под ipad, и встал вопрос о - как организовать перелистывание с одной формы на другую. Почти все приложения под ipad/iphone используют именно перелистывание. Либо оно автоматом переходит на другую форму при листании пальцем если есть в приложении др формы или надо программно реализовывать?

Answer (score 1):

Начать можно [отсюда](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html). Пример с прелистыванием ([UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_21)).

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду вникать